# How to check if value exist in sqlite table

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to check if a value is present in my sqlite table. What I am trying to do is check if a variable is equal to a verified `userID`. Meaning they have previously created an account and have been given a `userID` that is currently being stored in the table. How it works is a user scans their tag (rfid) and if the tag being scanned matches a `userID` in the sqlite table the program will print "User verified " and if the tag does not contain a `userID` being stored print"Denied,Users doesnt exist "

My issue is the userID variable is not pulling data. It is always empty which is throwing the else statement the print"Denied,Users doesnt exist " . I know the data is being stored in the table but it is just not being retrieved from the table. Any suggestions?

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3 as sql
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522

reader = SimpleMFRC522()


global tagID

def chk():
    Database = sql.connect('MedaDataBase.db')
    # cursor
    c= Database.cursor()

    #Scanning tag
    tagID = reader.read()

#If tag is scanned
    if tagID:
    
        idTag= (tagID,)

    #Query database for userID that Equals the idTag variable  
        query = 'SELECT userID FROM Users "WHERE" userID = "idTag"'
    
        c.execute(query)
        c.fetchone()
     
    #if userId equals idTag hash       
        if query == idTag: #if userID is returned
            print('User Verified')
        else:
            print('Denied')
        Database.close()
```

Comment: There are a number of issues with your code - I recommend keeping all database interactions in a single function; global variables are only defined once, outside of a function, by convention they're UPPERCASE. Finally - I suggest getting the uid_tag from the reader and only then querying the DB with the following `f"SELECT userID FROM Users WHERE uidTag = {uid_tag}"`.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:
The query seems to have an extra character that might be causing your issue.

```py
query = 'SELECT userID FROM Users'  #instead of SELECT, userID FROM Users
```

Your connection steps also seem to be intercepting each other/in a different order than needed, and the variable definition is referencing `reader.read()`. I am not familiar with its function, but I believe you can just use `fetch` which is in your checker method.

You may want to simplify your work by combining the checker step into the query like so:
*Now includes update to get user input for the uID*

```py
def chk(uID):
    global r
    Database = sql.connect('MedaDataBase.db')
    # cursor
    c= Database.cursor()
    #Query uid database and execute
    #assuming these are both ints (otherwise, make sure to use quotes on your WHERE clause)
    var = (uID,) #for security/to avoid injection
    query = 'SELECT userID FROM Users WHERE userID = ?' 
    c.execute(query, var)
    #fetch results (where the issue arises)
    row = c.fetchone() #since userID is unique, you'd only get the next row 
    if row[0]: #if userID is returned
        print('User Verified')
    else:
        print('Denied')
    Database.close()
```

I am leaving the step of getting input outside the method. This is because you might need to get the ID in multiple slots, and you can just call the method when needed

```py
#get user ID
user_ID = int(input('Please enter your user ID: '))
#call function to check
chk(user_ID)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Ill make the corrections and get back to you. The `reader.read()` references the GPIO pins on my raspberry pi , its what reads the rfid tag.

Comment: Ah gotcha! Thank you for teaching me about that `reader.read()` and good luck!

Comment: So I tried out the code and I believe it will work but I am having some issues. Is there a way to get the `query` to fetch a value only if it `var` and `userID` are equal. In order for uID to be given a value, it first must be inputted by a user.

Comment: You could have an input function for getting this. Updating the above to reflect.

Comment: the `reader.read()` acts like a input function, the tag has to be swiped in order for the `tagID` to be given a value. So I guess I am goin to have to create a method to first get the tagID then check if that returned value is in the database. I have edited the code above.

Comment: This should work given the interchangeable function for getting the input. If this is publicly available, don't forget to account for SQL injection by using parameters. Thanks for teaching me something new!